# how to retrieve data from service callback function in angularjs ? please find my program bugs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("searchController",['$scope','searchByNameService', function($scope, searchByNameService) {

    $scope.searchName = "raj";
    $scope.doSearchByName = function () {
        alert("inside controller " + $scope.searchName);

        searchByNameService.searchByName($scope.searchName, function(r) {
            alert("inside service " + r);

            $scope.custno = r.custno;
            $scope.name = r.name;
            $scope.city = r.city;
            $scope.mobile = r.mobile;
            alert("name " + r.name + " " + " city " + r.city + " mobile " + r.city);

        });
    };//service

}])

app.service('searchByNameService',['$http','$log', function($http, $log){

    //$log.log("service instantiation ..");

    this.searchByName = function(custName, cb){
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:4545/customers/' + custName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(resp){
            cb(resp.data) // it does not return data , but it display on console
            $log.log(resp.data);
        }, function(res){
            $log.error('Service :: ERROR OCCURED,OR SERVER PROBLEM....');
            debugger;
        });
    };

}]);//service
```

Comment: First thing first, any errors in the console?

Comment: *"please find my program bugs"* is not how this site works. Please read [ask].

Comment: You should return your data ..

Comment: on console no error it show output like :                                            
 Array(1)0: {custno: 101, name: "raj", city: "pune", mobile: 95270778, famillymember: "4", …}   proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: If it logs in your console, then you probably don't handle the return value well.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the data:

```
this.searchByName = function(custName, cb){
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:4545/customers/' + custName,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(resp){
            cb(resp.data) // it does not return data , but it display on console
            $log.log(resp.data);
            return resp; // <---------------------------------   Return the data
        }, function(res){
            $log.error('Service :: ERROR OCCURED,OR SERVER PROBLEM....');
            debugger;
        });
    };
```